# Django AdminDateWidget only appearing once on form

Tags: django, forms, widget

I'm fairly new to using the django framework and I'm putting together a site using the AdminDateWidget. With the help of another post I've got the widget working but it's only appearing once on the form when I've defined two fields. If I comment out either of the fields it will appear on the other but I'm unable to get it to appear on both at the same time.

Code from my forms.py

```
class CertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = cert
        #fields = ('title','created_date')
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
                'created_date': AdminDateWidget(),
                'expiry_date': AdminDateWidget(),
}
```

Any suggests?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the code from your template?

Answer (score 0):

got this working finally

forms.py - pretty much speaks for itself

```
import datetime
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from .models import cert

class CertForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = cert
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
           'created_date': widgets.AdminDateWidget,
           'expiry_date': widgets.AdminDateWidget,
        }
```

urls.py -

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog # **add this**
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cert_list, name='cert_list'),
    path('cert/<int:pk>/', views.cert_detail, name='cert_detail'),
    path('cert/new', views.cert_new, name='cert_new'),
    path('jsi18n', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'), # **add this**
]
```

base.html template add this block

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/admin/css/widgets.css' %}">
<style>.calendar>table>caption{caption-side:unset}</style>
{{ form.media }}
```

ie

```
% load static %}

{% load admin_static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}" />

<html>
    <head>
        <title>SSL Cert Management</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/cert.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/admin/css/widgets.css' %}">
        <style>.calendar>table>caption{caption-side:unset}</style><!--caption fix for bootstrap4-->
        {{ form.media }}
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <a href="{% url 'cert_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        <h1><a href="/">SSL Cert Management</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```